# How to get a UITableViewCell from out of view and scroll it into view

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my code when user adds a new item to the list, the App adds it to an array of items, sorts them, then calls `[tableView reloadData]`. Because of sorting the list, sometimes newly added item goes out of view. I'm going to get the `UITableViewCell` of newly added item when it's out of view and scroll it back into view.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I add the record to tag of each cell:

```
cell.tag = listItems.recordID;
```

In `addNewItem` method after adding new item and sorting the items:

```
for (int i = 0; i<listItems.count; i++)
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    int tag = cell.tag;
    if (tag == newItemRecordID)
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                              atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                      animated:YES];
}
```

When the cell is out of view `tag` property returns `0` and I can't get the cell.

How is it possible do get that cell?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns nil for cells that are not currently visible, so your basic algorithm is faulty.  Since all methods sent to nil return 0, tag will be 0 for any cells not currently visible.  Lebyrt's solution should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, it would be better to use something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listItems.count; i++)
{
    // Replace 'ListItem' with the name of your class.
    ListItem *listItem = [listItems objectAtIndex:i];
    if (listItem.recordID == newItemRecordID)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                              atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                      animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set cell tag as the following:

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row;
```

After setting cell tag, you can call your function:

```
for (int i = 0; i<listItems.count; i++)
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    int tag = cell.tag;
    if (tag == newItemRecordID)
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                              atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                      animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: After 6 cells, cell.tag returns 0. FYI There are 6 cells visible in the view